# Why has my Battery Icon stopped updating in Linux?

Tags: linux, laptop, battery, power, arch-linux

I noticed something funky happening over the past week. My battery icon stopped updating. For a more specific definition, here's the expected and current behavior in detail:

**Expected Behavior**

- Change to "Charging" icon when plugged in and charging - and display the appropriate tooltip.
- While charging, show a gradually increasing indicator of battery level - and show up-to-date percentage in the tooltip.
- Change to "Discharging icon when plugged in and discharging - and display the appropriate tooltip.
- While discharging, show a gradually decreasing indicator of battery level - and show up-to-date percentage in tooltip.

**Current Behavior**

- Get the current state and percentage when Xorg starts.
- Never change anything.

  - If it was plugged in when X started, it will show the "Charging" icon even if I unplug it, etc.

---

On the plus side, infinite battery life! On the minus side, it's all a lie. I've spent some time troubleshooting this and trying to figure out what the heck is going on. Here's a list of the assumptions I've made, steps I've taken to test them, and the results.

The troubleshooting steps are in a wacky order because I wasn't directly troubleshooting the battery icon, but doing other stuff too.

1. "Is the system reporting the power state incorrectly...?"

   - Run `acpi`

     - Results from `acpi` are correct - not stuck.
2. "Must be some weird config setting or conflict causing the weirdness!"

   - Installed fresh Arch Linux on an unused drive.

     - Battery icon is still stuck.
   - Try a different Desktop Environment.

     - Same problem in LXDE, Xfce, and Enlightenment.
3. "Maybe there was a kernel update that broke something."

   - install 3.10 LTS kernel.

     - Still broken.

So yeah, I'm not sure what the problem is. Does anyone know?

Basic information about my default setup:

- OS: Arch Linux
- Kernel Version: 3.14.1 / 3.10.47
- Desktop Environment: Xfce
- Notebook: Acer Aspire S7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here (OS, desktop env, kernel). Seems related to upower in combination with systemd issue: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/39893

Possible fix (did not try yet): https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xfce4-power-manager-git/

Alternative: Use package and plugin xfce4-battery-plugin from xfce4-goodies

Comment: using `xfce4-power-manager-git` from the AUR does fix the problem described, but has its own issues (The icon doesn't display properly, shows a generic placeholder icon)